How to show only selected strips on dope sheet in VSE?
I'm using Blender 4.0.2 on Windows 10.
In VSE, I would like the dope sheet to display only the keyframe data for the selected strip(s), but it shows all the data for all the strips. It's very messy and hard to use.
I know that pressing [.] on the numpad moves me to the selected strip, but still sometimes, especially when a few strips are selected, the keyframe data is spread out so much that I have to hunt it down.
See image below. Thank you :)
Maitrisingha


try selecting your strip and then shift-h

In the dope sheet, try enabling the "Show Only Selected" filter:

It's enabled by default.
